# Ayuda, Como gestionar la descarga de un archivo usando $.fileDownload desde un controller?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, spring

Tengo un método que recupera datos del formulario, y los pasa como parámetros a un método del servicio para realizar la consulta, este método me regresa una respuesta json, y en la vista me manda un mensaje si es que hay datos o no datos en la consulta.

Ahora lo que quiero hacer es obtener el resultado de ese query, y si hay datos, que me descargue un archivo con esa informacion y si no, que muestre el mensaje, para ello tengo dos métodos en el controller, uno el de la respuesta json y el otro el que tiene la funcionalidad de la descarga del archivo, al cual le paso la lista que obtuve del primer método

```
@RequestMapping(value="view/obtieneInfo")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
@ResponseBody
public  JsonResponse obtieneInfor(@ResponseBody Factura fact, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse respons) throws ControlException{

JsonResponse response = new JsonResponse();
response.setExito(0);
response.setDatos(null);

try{
List<Factura> factList = obtieneInfoService.consultaDatos(id, cvePag, fecha);
if(factList !=null && !factList.isEmpty){
 response.setExito(1);
 response.setDatos(factList);

}else{
  log.info("Esta vacio");
}
}catch(ControlException e){
   throw new ControlException("Error", e);
}
return response;
}



@RequestMapping(value="view/obtieneArchivo")
public  void obtieneArchivo(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, @RequestParam ("factList") String [] factList ) throws ControlException{

try{

if(factList !=null){

 response.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/csv");
 response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=archivo.csv");

 PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            out.write("columna1,columna2,columna3");
            out.write("\n");

            for(String factu: factList){
                out.write(factu.toCSVRepresentation());
                out.write("\n");
            }
             out.flush();
             out.close();

}else{
  log.info("Esta vacio");
}
}catch(ControlException e){
   throw new ControlException("Error", e);
}
}
```

En mi entidad Factura, tengo este método:

```
public String toCSV(){
  StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
  builder.append(getId()).append(“,”),
.
.
.
return builder.toString(),
}
```

y este es mi código de la vista, en el cual tengo dos funciones, una se llama obtienInf(), y lo que hace es  pues pasar la respuesta del json y validar si hay o no datos, y tengo otra función que se llama descarga(), la cual contiene la url de mi método 2 que realiza la descarga del archivo, y esta función la mando a llamar dentro de obtieneInf(), en la parte donde valida que si haya datos

```
function obtieneInf(){
    if(consultar()){
        if(!HelperForm.valido(consulta, validator)){
            return;

        }else{

            var data = Helper.obtenerJsonForm(consulta);
            var url="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/view/obtieneInfo";
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                contentType: "application/json",
                url: url,
                data: data,
                dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response){
                if(response.exito==1){
                    HelperDialogo.mostrar("Si hay registros");
                  factList = response.datos;
                   descarga(factList);
                }else{
                    HelperDialogo.mostrar("No se encontraron registros");
                }

            },
            error: function(response){
                HelperDialogo.mostrarError(response);
            }

            });
        }
    }
}

function descarga(factList){

    var url="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/view/obtieneArchivo?factList=" +factList;
    $.fileDownload(url)
      .done(
        function(){
            Helper.muestraInf("Se descargo correctamente");
        }

      )
    .fail(
        function(){
            Helper.muestraInf("Ocurrio un  error en la descarga");
        }
    );
}
</script>
<form:form id="consulta" modelAttribute="consultaForm">
  <tr>
    <td><label>ID/label></td>
    <td><form: input type="text"  id="idPago" path="id"/></td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
    <td><label>CLAVE PAGO</label></td>
    <td><form: input type="text" id="clavePago" path="clavePago"/></td>
   </tr>

   <tr>


   <tr>
    <td><label>FECHA PAGO</label></td>
    <td><form: input type="text" id="fechaPago" path="fechaPago"/></td>
    <input type="button" onclick="obtieneInf()"></input>
   </tr>
</form:form>
```

y al llenar mi formulario y hacer click en el boton, me lanza un mensaje diciendo que si hay datos, que es lo que tengo en mi funcion y despues me manda otro mensaje de que ocurrio un error en la descarga, que es del metodo descarga() y me lanza el error:

Failed to convrt value of type java.lang.String to required type util.List; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException cannot convert value of type String to required type com.mx.Entity

que esta mal, mi método del controller al pasarle la lista?, o como le hago para que me descargue el archivo?
esta bien mi método de descarga()?, cuando en la url tengo
"${pageContext.request.contextPath}/view/obtieneArchivo?factList=" +factList;

Necesito su ayuda, gracias.

Comment: Hola Root93, se están reportando varias preguntas que en realidad tienen contenido duplicado,  te sugiero crear una que este basada en lo que indique [ask] de esta forma te aseguro obtendrías la ayuda que necesitas, hasta el día de hoy no has realizado el [tour] para saber como funciona el sitio. Saludos!.

Answer (score 1):

El error que te esta mostrando es por la siguiente linea:

```
@RequestParam ("factList") List<Factura> factList
```

Lo que te dice la consola:

> Failed to convrt value of type java.lang.String to required type
>   util.List; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException cannot
>   convert value of type String to required type com.mx.Entity

Tu vista está mandando un tipo `String` y no un tipo `List<Factura>`. Al final con esta linea te lo dice:

> convert value of type String to required type com.mx.Entity

Que significa "convierte el valor de tipo String a requerido de tipo com.mx.Entity".

Intenta debuggear. Cambia la linea que te señale por `@RequestParam("factList") String[] factList` y revisa que es lo que en realidad estás recibiendo.

Comment: Angel te saludo, se reporto en el sistema que estas realizando "respuestas duplicadas" : https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/173023/como-descargar-un-archivo-con-filedownload-usando-java/173145#173145 Revisar [answer], saludos.

Comment: @Jorgesys Es correcto. Eliminare algúna. Reporte las preguntas tambien por que son duplicadas.

Comment: Gracias por tu reporte @Angel ya lo recibimos, saludos!

Comment: @Angel, ya lo cambié y ya hace la descarga del archivo,  pero en el for que recorre mi lista, Como es del tipo PreFactura y ya lo cambié a String, sale cannot convert from element String yo PreFactura, pero si lo cambio ya no me reconoce la línea de abajo que está en out.write(prefactura.toCSVRepresentation());

Comment: Ya que ese método pertenece a mi entidad PreFactura, ahí como le puedo hacer? De ante mano muchas gracias

Comment: Estoy un poco perdido con tu comentario. Actualiza la pregunta con el nuevo código y señala la parte que no te funciona. No borres lo anterior, solo agrega lo nuevo para tener referencia.

Comment: Ya la edite, es que en esa línea mando a llamar al método toCSV, que está adentro de mi entidad, pero como ya no es una lista de entidad, sino de String, pues no la encuentra y sale error, y es que con esa línea pinto los valores en el archivo que descargo.

Comment: No veo `PreFactura` en tu código. No se donde lo estas manejando en tu controller. Solo veo `Factura`. ¿Es ese? También veo un método `toCSVRepresentation()` ¿Es al que te refieres? -- Cuando decía que actualizaras me refería al nuevo código que tienes por que siento que estoy dando palos de ciego.  En otro punto. Estás recibiendo un `String[]`. ¿Qué es lo que estás recibiendo en este string? Eso no lo pusiste en la actualización.

Comment: @Angel, si perdón, es Factura mi entidad, donde tengo el método toCSVRepresentation(),  es que actualice el código de mi método  obtieneArchivo, por lo que me indicaste, la lista de String, pero al realizar ese cambio, sale el error en la linea out.write(factu.toCSVRepresentation()); que esta adentro del for, porque ese método es de la entidad Factura, no del String.  Lo que pretendo hacer es recuperar los datos de la lista de mi primer metodo, porque ya trae la info, y con esa info llenar mi archivo y que se  descargue

Comment: @Root93 ¿Pudiste resolver el problema?

Comment: @Angel, aún no he podido resolver ese tema